# API de Notificação do PagSeguro recebendo erro 403

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Olá, estou fazendo a integração da API do PagSeguro de maneira transparente e no ambiente de teste (Sandbox), quando faço uma alteração no Status da transação la no painel do PagSeguro, o sistema deles mandam uma requisição, porem no status http recebido, da 403 (proibido).

A minha dúvida é, quando o sistema deles acessam o controlador respectivo do link de notificação do meu sistema, é para dar algum tipo de retorno? Segue abaixo o que tenho feito até agora:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Notifications(string notificationCode, string notificationType)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br");

        if (notificationCode.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            return Content("ERROR - Required code of transaction");

        try
        {
            EnvironmentConfiguration.ChangeEnvironment(isSandbox);

            AccountCredentials credentials = PagSeguroConfiguration.Credentials(isSandbox);

            Transaction transaction = NotificationService.CheckTransaction(credentials, notificationCode);

            var dados = db.PsTransactions.FirstOrDefault(t => t.code.Equals(transaction.Code));
            if (dados != null)
            {
                if (dados.lasteventdate.Equals(transaction.LastEventDate))
                    return Content("Transaction already exists");
                dados.date = transaction.Date;
                dados.lasteventdate = transaction.LastEventDate;
                dados.status = PagSeguro.TransactionStatusToString(transaction.TransactionStatus);

                db.Entry(dados).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            Infraestrutura.Notifications.Transactions(dados);
            TransactionsHub.NotifyCurrentTransactions();
        }
        catch (PagSeguroServiceException ex)
        {
            return Content("ERROR - " + ex.Message);
        }

        return Content("SUCCESS - Transaction update");    
    }
```

E segue o log da notificação do SandBox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você o que (semanticamente) significa o código 403?

Comment: é uma resposta HTTP, tal como o 404 (nao encontrado), o 403 é acesso negado @jbueno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui identificar qual o motivo desse retorno. Quando estou no ambiente de desenvolvimento (localhost:44333) o envio automático de quando se altera o status no sandbox de alguma forma não funciona.

Para funcionar, é só clicar no botão **"Reenviar Notificação Local"** e independente de aparecer que deu erro, disparou a ação no *Controller*.